# Выбрать всё после последнего слэша

Tags: php, wordpress

Как я могу получить всё после последнего слэша? Например, у меня есть урл `https://domain.com/auto/news/636911f29a79xx23e62887971` как я могу получить `636911f29a79xx23e62887971`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Достаточно просто (Regex не нужен):

$str = substr($url, strrpos($url, '/') + 1);